# How to call a app function from a Flask blueprint

Tags: python, flask

I want to move some commonly used parts of my webapps to Flask blueprints for better reuse. But some of the routes will need functionality which is specific to a webapp. An example would be a simple form submission where everything is handled by the blueprint, only the form validation would have to be defined by the implementing app.

How can I tell a blueprint view to call a function of the app. With inheritance I would create a abstract function which would be filled out by them implementing webapp. But I am lost how to do something similar with a blueprint.

Edit:

I am using Class based views, but the following snippet trys to explain what I am looking for:

```
@my_blueprint.route('/submit')
def submit():
    errors = current_app.check_for_errors(request.form)  # <--- How to?
    return render_template('result.html', errors=error)
```

The `errors = current_app.check_for_errors(request.form)` is the one I don't know ho to implement. Sub-classing `flask.Flask` is the only way I can come up with, but this doesn't feel right.

Comment: do you have an example of a function of app?? some code and what you need to do, please....